# Correct/Recommended way of Formatting Currency in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've been running into a UI issue due to currency formatting.

Two different properties...

```
Public Property ShippingRate() As Decimal
     Get
         Return _shippingRate
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
          _shippingRate = value
     End Set
End Property

Public Property TotalShipping() As Decimal
     Get
          Return _totalShipping
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
          _totalShipping = Math.Round(value, 2)
     End Set
End Property
```

Both of these properties are called in various parts of the code, but they both are called in this way...

```
Me.txtBoxOutput.Text = myObject.ShippingRate.ToString("c")
Me.txtBoxOutput2.Text = myObject2.TotalShipping.ToString("c")
```

When I debug, if I get a decimal that is `10.345` for both these properties (TotalShipping could eventually be ShippingRate +/- other logic), I see different output in the textboxes.  The property that is rounded will be `$10.34` and the other property which is not rounded is `$10.35`.

I assumed since I was rounding to the 2nd decimal point that it would round that 5 up, which the `ToString("c")` is implicitly doing.

So, my question is....what is the correct way to display the currency.  I've done a little research on Shipping Rates (UPS and Fedex) and how they will often use the 5 in the thousandth decimal place.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings is where I go whenever I need to remember how to format numbers in .NET...

Comment: If you want the same result, add MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero when rounding. But, why are your rounding that value? The rounding procedure and the result it should produce is something you codify long before you code it (you shouldn't be surprised). If you have determined that the banker's rounding is the *right* path, then apply it everywhere (VB.Net uses this type of rounding).

Comment: @Jimi Yes, thank you.  I dove into the ````MidpointRounding```` to see the differences.  And from further research it seems like Bankers Rounding, the default, is the best way to proceed.  But as far as why I'm rounding, it was not intentional.  These properties are used in separate DLLs, and the rounded property was added way before my time but it is the only place where it is done that way.  Every other ````Decimal```` property uses the raw decimal value.

Comment: "Round(Decimal, Int32)
Rounds a decimal value to a specified number of fractional digits, and rounds midpoint values to the nearest even number." From the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_Int32_ The catch here is even number.